# Blue Screen installing Adobe AIR Applications

Tags: windows-xp, bsod, adobe-air

I have the problem of Blue Screen when installing any Adobe AIR on Windows XP, 32bits, Service Pack 3, in a corporative environment, I've created an Adobe AIR application that it works fine on many machines on Windows XP, Vista and Windows 7 but I'm facing problems on 2 PC's with Windows XP and using Debugging tools I found the log file (.DMP) that says:

```
EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

FAULTING_IP: 
windrvNT+1703
ba3d9703 668b08          mov     cx,word ptr [eax]

TRAP_FRAME:  a4d04c70 -- (.trap 0xffffffffa4d04c70)
ErrCode = 00000000
eax=00000000 ebx=ba3dd142 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=0012e70c edi=a4d04d64
eip=ba3d9703 esp=a4d04ce4 ebp=a4d04d04 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0008  ss=0010  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0030  gs=0000             efl=00010246
windrvNT+0x1703:
ba3d9703 668b08          mov     cx,word ptr [eax]        ds:0023:00000000=????
Resetting default scope

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  2
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  DRIVER_FAULT
BUGCHECK_STR:  0x8E
PROCESS_NAME:  Adobe AIR Appli

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from ba3dd23a to ba3d9703

STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
windrvNT+1703
ba3d9703 668b08          mov     cx,word ptr [eax]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0
SYMBOL_NAME:  windrvNT+1703
FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner
MODULE_NAME: windrvNT
IMAGE_NAME:  windrvNT.sys
DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  409f405c
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x8E_windrvNT+1703
BUCKET_ID:  0x8E_windrvNT+1703
Followup: MachineOwner
```

If some one knows how to fix this issue. I've already searched for Folder Lock and this file: `windrvNT.sys`  is no longer on those PC's.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about it, I fixed the problem:

Besides the file mentioned on the minidump file as : windrvNT.sys  I used regedit to find the rest of the traces for this application and I erased every entry on the registry and after a doing a reboot I can install my application again.

Notice that you should have already this Windows patch : WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86

Regards.
Joe